# PLL design requirements

Tags: pll

In a pll loop is it required to have a non-inverting buffer (using op-amp) after the loop filter. Will it help to reduce the lock-in time of the pll in any way?

Comment: It is not required. End of story.

Comment: A buffer adds time-delay, thus phaseshift, and degrades the loop stability and alters the final settling. As will any additional delay.

Comment: _If_ it is **required** then that implies the circuit will not work without it. Therefore...